# Equivalent of WM_MOVE

Tags: macos, winapi

What's is the equivalent of window's WM_MOVE in Mac OS ? I have to capture a mouse event when one moves window using left click. In windows we can capture this event using WM_MOVE but i could not find similar event in Mac OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cocoa, look at the `NSWindow` and `NSNotificationCenter` classes (or alternately assign a delegate instance to an `NSWindow`, which receives notifications implicitly just by implementing appropriate methods).

For instance you can use `windowWillMove:` or `windowDidMove:` notifications to notice when a window has been moved *by the user*.  This is not sent continuously; it is sent when the user starts moving a window, or pauses while moving the window.  If you need fine-grained control over mouse events you can subclass the window and implement methods from its superclass `NSResponder`.